# Mapping the TFS State field with HP QC Sync

Tags: tfs, synchronization, alm

When i sync the HP ALM defects with TFS im getting this issue. im trying too sync the HP ALM Status field with TFS State field .

Execution log file

Update: threw an exception,skipping this entity and moving to the next, exception:update: general error AutomationException: AdapterException: Error in method TfsComEntityManager.UpdateWorkItemState , Unknown exception occurred. Cannot update State field with value:Resolved . 
NEED HELP !!

Comment: can you please re-edit your question for easy reading?

Comment: Im  synchronizing HP ALM Status field with TFS State field  with HP ALM Synchronizer 12.53  and im heaving that issue above.

Comment: Duplicate with this question in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930185/how-to-sync-hp-alm-status-field-with-tfs-state-field-with-hp-alm-synchronizer-12 . Since you have figured out the issue. Suggest you either add the solution in the answer or delete the question in SO.