# how to Sync HP ALM Status field with TFS State field with HP ALM Synchronizer 12.53

Tags: synchronization, hp-alm

I'm having issues to Sync HP ALM Status field with TFS State field with HP ALM Synchronizer 12.53, this is the issue that I'm getting Update conflicted records:

> threw an exception,skipping this entity and moving to the next,
>   exception:update: general error AutomationException: AdapterException:
>   Error in method TfsComEntityManager.UpdateWorkItemState , Unknown
>   exception occurred. Cannot update State field with value:Closed .

Comment: HP synchronization framework works such a way that it brings current state of HP to TFS. Probably this could be the scenario where your source defect is closed and in tfs, synchronizer tries to close the tfs workitem defect which is mostly wrong transition from TFS point of view. i.e. you can not set Closed/Resolved at the time of create or can not jump directly on Closed from New/Active

Comment: see http://www.opshub.com, integration manager is capable of dealing with any such kind of scenarios

Comment: thanks for your answer i figured out a way to sync them with HP ALM Synchronizer

Answer (score 1):

thank you for using HPE ALM Synchronizer.
For syncing between ALM and TFS, we need pay attention to TFS workflow.

Generally speaking, when you saw some errors about change the state, you can manually change TFS record to ALM values (state and reason) by using Team Explorer or browser. If you couldn't do this in TFS client, means the workflow are not allow the transition.

We saw some customer didn't map reason in Synchronizer some times. It's not recommended, because both state and reason are very important in TFS workflow.
Best practice is making ALM and TFS has same rules of state/reason transition.

Last, Synchronizer is very smart to change state & reason, it can find any possible combination to reach the final state in 12.53. However, we faced some bugs in 12.50 to 12.52. So its recommended to update to 12.53.